# Create a JavaScript spreadsheet based on input

Tags: javascript, html, spreadsheet

I am trying to learn web programming and Javascript.

I'm trying to take whatever the user copied from an Excel spreadsheet and create a JavaScript spreadsheet/table that includes dropdowns out of it.

So basically the user would paste the input into a blank field, press the submit button, and JavaScript would generate an Excel-like spreadsheet which would have the data sorted accordingly. The dropdowns would be at the top of each column and allow the user to select either ready/not ready. This is being designed for a confluence WIKI page.

This is what I have so far, right now the code parses the input-field and creates a multi-dimensional array. After that, the array will be logged on the console. I need help getting everything displayed on the wiki page.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
    <button id="loadPaste">parse</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var excel = new Array();
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#loadPaste').click(function() {
                var text = $('#textarea').val();
                var rows = text.split("\n");
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    excel[i] = rows[i].split("\t");
                }
                console.log(excel);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, however the speadsheet would get displayed on the WIKI page itself. The spreadsheet would get displayed after the user paste their input in the provided field and press enter

Comment: Might make things easier if you use an xml parser `var xml = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString($('#textarea').val(), 'text/xml')`

Comment: Ok let me look into that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Lets close this one: //THIS IS @Downgoat response with little explanation about xml parser.

use an xml parser `var xml = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString($('#textarea').val(), 'text/xml')`

```js
var text, parser, xmlDoc;

text = "<bookstore><book>" +
"<title>Everyday Italian</title>" +
"<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>" +
"<year>2005</year>" +
"</book></bookstore>";

parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```